# IE9/10: Meteor.users.attachSchema - Object doesn't support property or method 'attachSchema' using Collection2 in Meteor.js

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor, meteor-collection2

I get the following JavaScript runtime error when running my Meteor app in Internet Explorer 9 and 10 (I haven't checked before 9, and there's no issue in IE11):
Object doesn't support property or method 'attachSchema'

Problem line: Meteor.users.attachSchema( Schemas.User );

I don't get this error for any of my other Collections that use attachSchema.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
UsersCollection = Meteor.users;
UsersCollection.attachSchema( Schemas.User );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually originally had that, and it didn't work either, which led me to try the built-in Meteor.users collection.

Comment: Could you try using my suggestion in a file named  `main.js` in the root of your project folder